# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have written code using matmul, but I am getting the following error:

```
   "ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 3)"
```

Code:

```
    R = [[0.40348195], [0.38658295], [0.82931052]]
    V = [0.33452744, 0.33823673, 0.32723583]
    print("Rt_p: ", R)
    B = np.matmul(V,np.transpose(R))/pow(LA.norm(R), 2)
    print("B", B)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are transposing a Matrix with 3 rows and 1 column to a Matrix with 3 columns and 1 row.
Then you are multiplying it with a similar Matrix (also 3 columns 1 row) which is incorrect mathematically. So you can either remove the transpose function or define your R Matrix as 1 row 3 columns and then transpose it. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) for further information.

Answer (score 4):

Try to check your X_train shape and then check the shape of the test data which you input into the .predict() function. if the number of features are different like
X_train(2323,22) and for test data (3534,20) then it will show this type of erro

Answer (score 0):

multiplication of vectors/matrix is being done using columns of one vector to rows of the other... so, in your case, according your structure, you do not need transpose

```
import numpy as np

R = np.array([[0.40348195], [0.38658295], [0.82931052]])
V = np.array([0.33452744, 0.33823673, 0.32723583])
print("Rt_p: ", R)
B = (V @ R)/pow(np.linalg.norm(R), 2)
print("B: ", B)

# B:  [0.53711245]
```